# android samsung how to turn off adaptive sound from code?

Tags: android

Hi i recently bought a samsung a14 android 13 but the sound is really bad on it. From googling i have determined the cause to be adaptive sound settings where removed by samsung and it is on by default i have been checking for shortcuts to the settings such as other settings

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/2acaf22/src/com/android/settings
```

as it is still part of google code and should be there its just samsung removed it with a ui update and i really dont want to restart the phone so i dont get the update

kind regards and help would be great

Comment: Still being part of AOSP doesn't mean its still there on a Samsung device.  No OEM ships pure AOSP.  They all make modifications.  That's part of the point of open source.  It may be there under the hood, but it also may not be

Comment: I think it was there until a ui update so im 90% sure it is there samsung just removed the option from the menu and broke half there phones cos im not the only one having this problem but thanks so much for reply i just need to get my phone usable or else samsung can have it back